# Check which file header was included from?

Tags: php, redirect, header

I have a header.php file that will redirect the user to the homepage on any page if they are not logged in. I'm running into an issue in that the homepage also includes the header and can't have a header to itself. What is the best way to prevent this? I'm thinking a flag I set before my include in the homepage but that seems kinda dirty and inelegant.

Comment: "that the homepage also includes the header" -- what does it mean?

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code** to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a condition:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != "your.homepage.com")
  header( "Location: http://your.homepage.com" ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could add something like this:

```
if (pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME) !== 'homepage'){
   header ('location:header.php'); 
   exit;
}
```